# SP 2013 REST API retrieve values from lookup library

Tags: lookup-column, rest

I have a custom list 'MyList', containing a (single value) lookup field 'MyLookupField', which points to a library 'MyLibrary'. I now want to retrieve all items from 'MyList', including the Link to the corresponding file in the library.

I can lookup the Id or Title from the library:

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,Template/Id&$expand=Template
```

But I was not successful to retrive the link to the file in the library:

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,Template/FieldLeafRef&$expand=Template
```

Any idea if it is possible to retrieve the link to the file in a REST call or does this require a CAML query?

Answer (score -2):

Fetch additional lookup columns values in REST

lookupList -- List1 :  col1, col2

List2: col3(lookupof col1)

template:
$select=LookupColName/LookupListcolName1,LookupColName/LookupListcolName2&$expand=LookupColName/LookupListcolName1,LookupColName/LookupListcolName2

Example
$select=col3/col1,col3/col2&$expand=col3/col1,col3/col2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to generally retrieve lookup values in a REST call, but what I need is the retrueve the link to a file in a looked up library.